# Error with tests in Android Studio when using ReLinker to load libraries

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, bugsnag

When I try to run my unit tests, ReLinker is complaining.
I've added Bugsnag, and it works as it should. Later I add ReLinker like here: https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/android/faq/
After adding those two lines I am no longer able to run my tests.

My application onCreate contains:

```
ReLinker.loadLibrary(this, "bugsnag-ndk")
        ReLinker.loadLibrary(this, "bugsnag-plugin-android-anr")
        Bugsnag.start(this, config)
```

Whenever I try to run my tests using RobolectricTestRunner, I get the following errors:

```
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 29 requires Java 9 (have Java 8). Tests won't be run on SDK 29 unless explicitly requested.
[Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 30 requires Java 9 (have Java 8). Tests won't be run on SDK 30 unless explicitly requested.

Could not find 'bugsnag-ndk.dll'. Looked for: [armeabi-v7a], but only found: [java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 10
lib\([^\\]*)\bugsnag-ndk.dll
          ^].
com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: Could not find 'bugsnag-ndk.dll'. Looked for: [armeabi-v7a], but only found: [java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 10
lib\([^\\]*)\bugsnag-ndk.dll
          ^].
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ApkLibraryInstaller.installLibrary(ApkLibraryInstaller.java:173)
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibraryInternal(ReLinkerInstance.java:180)
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibrary(ReLinkerInstance.java:136)
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:70)
    at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:51)
    at com.roardam.vvitas.Vvitas.onCreate(Vvitas.kt:19)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.lambda$installAndCreateApplication$0(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:288)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:86)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.installAndCreateApplication(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:288)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.setUpApplicationState(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:171)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:319)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:269)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've added ReLinker and Bugsnag with:

```
implementation 'com.github.KeepSafe:ReLinker:1.4.3'
implementation 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:5.+'
```

I am not entirely sure the problem is ReLinker, but I am able to run the tests when I remove the two lines loading libraries.

Please let me know if I haven't shown enough code, and I'll update my post with whatever code needed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a Relinker problem as it occurs when loading various other native libraries not just Bugsnag.